# How to create $2y$14 blowfish hash with python?

Tags: python

I'm setting up a new Fedora 29 box and want to create BLF-CRYPT passwords from python. I would like to create $2y$ hashes, but whatever I try, it doesn't raise up above $2b$. Initially it only did $2a$. Therefore I issued:

```
pip uninstall py-bcrypt
pip install passlib
pip install bcrypt
```

The passwords are created by:

```
from passlib.hash import bcrypt
hashed = bcrypt.using(rounds=14).hash("test")
hash

'$2b$14$9sAGvDrV0YEF3BBbofYCz.dNSaJZRDw2vfkFDY/5cwQzAxMNP4MVO'
```

How do I create $2y$ hashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html) you could use `ident` as param.

```
bcrypt.using(rounds=14, ident="2y").hash("test")
```